# Limit to HtmlPage.Window.Eval()

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I was wondering if there was a limit to HtmlPage.Window.Eval().

I am currently defining a url to create a mailto link, the content is auto generated by the silverlight application and then passed over for the user. However, when I call HtmlPage.Window.Eval("location.href='mailto:?Subject=my%20Application%20-%20Spot%2FOutright%20deal&body=Please%20find%20attached%20the%20following%20trade%20details...';");

The email is fairly large, however it is below the limit for the mailto uri. I was wondering if there was a limit to the size of the Eval method which may be causing me an issue, if I pass through a reduced message I am not getting any problems.

Is there an alternative way of doing this? I have tried HtmlPage.Window.Navigate, however this always opens a new window, even if I specify to use self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rob,

I have been running my url through encoding before sending it through to the function. From what I have read it appears that the mailto link when used in InternetExplorer struggles with a characterset exceeding around 512 characters. Whilst it is possible to extend this with settings I don't have the access to do this currently.

I ended up using the following script:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Eval("OpenEmailLink(" + uri + ")");

function OpenEmailLink(uri) {

        var win = window.open(uri, '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=0,height=0,left=-1000,top=-1000');
        if (win && win.open && !win.closed) win.close();
    }
```

There were some issues with the win object being null (this was due to the application treating it as a cross domain item and therefore not returning an object for me to then close. As such I have had to use a popup to launch the email client, it is far from the solution I had hoped for but limitations meant that I had to make do for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure you are encoding the text, I use:

```
string email = "mailto:" + "?subject=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(subject) + "&body=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(body);
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(email));
```

I think the character limit on a url is 2048.